# How to parse little chunks of JSON data in IOS?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a large JSON file.

If I use NSJSONSerialization or SwiftyJSON to parse this file, the app gives memory warnings then it gets crashed.

Best solution I can think of is, to parse the file as little (NSData) chunks.

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: You need to implement a custom mechanism for that, first of all you need to extract a valid chunk of json string from that file, then convert it to nsdata and then convert it to respective json object. (Obviously this operation will be too complex depending on your json structure)

Comment: I dont think JSON works like that, thats like trying to compile half a file of code... the JSON follows a schema that cant be parsed in little bits, that first opening bracer has to find its closing bracer at the end of the file, and to get there it has to parse whats in between it. Just making an educated guess here, but maybe im wrong. it would probably be better to actually split up your JSON file into appropriate bite sized chunks

Comment: Using small json files, instead of keeping all those in a single file will help in this scenario

Comment: @Midhun MP, file is downloaded from a server. I have no control over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SBJson4Parser` does what I want.

Answer (score -1):

How big are your JSON files? Do you have evidence that it is the JSON parser causing the problem? If the file is large, how many copies of the data to you have? I have no problems parsing a 20 MB JSON file on an iPhone 4, so what are you doing?

Comment: These are questions not an answer ;) You should post is as a comment probably?

Comment: They are rhetoric questions, presenting a plan of action.

Comment: How can "I have no problems parsing a 20 MB JSON file on an iPhone 4, so what are you doing?" present a plan of action? He knows he does something wrong. Even suggesting to use Instruments to know if there are zombie NSData objects is not an answer - it's just a suggestion. All rest of the questions (which are not rhetoric, as all of them have an answer) also are rather a helper than any solution. Nvm anyway, i'm not the downvoter, just wanted to present this point of view.